# Is there any way to convert Ember Object into plain javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I could not find any way to accomplish the task of such conversion as I could not find any means of getting Ember.js properties for the object. `Ember.keys` returns only the properties  I set in `create` or with `get` and the properties declared in `Ember.extend` do not show up there. I use such properties to set up default values (e.g. `[]` for array properties)

Comment: It looks like JSON.stringify also ignores "class properties"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I solve it with the following snippet:

```js
App.plainCopy = function (obj) {
  if (Ember.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(App.plainCopy);
  } else if (typeof(obj) === "object") {
    if (App.Plainable.detect(obj)) {
      return obj.plainCopy();
    } else {
      throw new Error(Ember.String.fmt("%@ is not Plainable", [obj]));
    }
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}

App.Plainable = Ember.Mixin.create({
  plainCopy: function() {
    var props = Ember.keys(this);
    var proto = this.constructor.prototype;
    for(p in proto) {
      if (proto.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof(this[p])!=="function") {
        props.push(p);
      }
    }
    var copy = {};
    props.forEach(function(p) {
      copy[p] = App.plainCopy(this.get(p));
    }, this);
    return copy;
  }
});
```

It does not go up the class hierarchy and does not look into mixins (as I use for data objects which are quite simple form that point of view)

Answer (score 33):

Here is my dirty workaround

```
var newModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));
```

Comment: Nowadays you could just use `model.toJSON()`.

Comment: Doesn't always work because of circular references however.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something similar to the person above, but I'd do it a little bit differently.

**Mixin**

```
App.NativeObject = Ember.Mixin.create({
    toNative: function() {
        var properties = [];
        for (var key in this) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(Ember.typeOf(object[key]), ['string', 'number', 'boolean']) !== -1) {
                properties.push(key);
            }
        }
        return this.getProperties(properties);
    }
});
```

**Object**

Then you just need to implement the `App.NativeObject` mixin in your objects that you would like the `toNative` on:

```
var Object = Ember.Object.extend(App.NativeObject, {
    name: 'Adam',
    count: 4
});
```

We then have the `toNative` method on all the objects that implement our mixin.

Obligatory jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jumUx/

Comment: your solution isn't recursive though

Comment: It's a small step from that to making it recursive, however.

Comment: yep, but take a look at this fork of your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/C2Rdn/ : if you create a class, "NativeObject" will include extra properties like `isDestroyed` etc.

Comment: Yep, those are difficult to exclude without specifying them explicitly. There is an example here: https://gist.github.com/Fordi/4279559 that overwrites the `create` method of `Ember.CoreObject` to *discover* properties on the object, otherwise we're unfortunately going to pick up the occasional property from the prototype chain.

Answer (score 2):

If your object is a subclass of ember-data model notice [you can use the `toJSON` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/1.13/classes/DS.Model/methods/toJSON?anchor=toJSON) otherwise you can use:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emberObj))
```

To grab any values which support native json serialization (i.e. not functions/methods)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`myModel.toJSON({includeId: true})`

I'm using Ember 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works quite well. Note, this should be ready only, as any changes to an object or array in the copied object will affect the original object

```
App.BaseValidations = Ember.Object.create({
    toObject: function() {
        var destination = {}
        for (var k in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof(this[k]) !== 'function') {
                destination[k] = this[k];
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

something quite simple that worked properly enough for me is :

```
Ember.Object.reopen({
    toJson: function() {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    }
});
```

at app loading time.

Answer (score 0):

With modern (3.17) ember, I've used `myEmberObject.getProperties('id', 'name', 'foo', 'bar')`

It produces a plain object.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution that may suit your needs while not being fully recursive for nested Ember objects:

```
// where myEmberObject is.. an ember object
var plainJavaScriptObject = myEmberObject.toJSON();
```

This will only include actual properties that you've defined and no Ember internals. Again, the drawback here is that any nested Ember objects will not, themselves, be converted but will appear as Strings in style of "".